# Algorithms for getting appropriate pictures for a given text

Tags: algorithm, nlp, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, information-retrieval

Is there any good algorithm out there which could analyze a paragraph of texts, and then choose a picture (say that we have a very good repository of pictures, or we have access to google image search) so that people can better understand the text by looking at the picture?

The application I'm thinking about is that such tool can automatically find pictures for web news, which may save a lot of work from webpage editors.

Comment: Just one clarification. You are asking about matching text to images, right? 

For the images you have, do you have any other information apart from the image itself? for instance tags, context, webpages they appear, ALT field, ...

Matching text to images by themselves is extremely complicated as the "semantics" or "concept" of an image is very difficult to compute (specially outside specific niche collections). 

If you have more information (text), the problem simplifies largely.

Comment: @miguelmalvarez I think it is the opposite. That is, given a text, we are trying to match a image from a picture repository to the text. And I think we could assume that we have a good computer vision algorithm for recognizing what are the things in side a given picture, or we could assume the pictures are well tagged.

Comment: @KelvinLee Using computer vision for this is too ambitious. You might as well do a PhD for creating such a system. The common approach used by google image search is to compare tags with search query. The easiest option for you is to use a google image search api.

Comment: Ok,if you assume that you have a textual description of an image, you can simplify the problem ignoring completely the image, and "observing" it as a document, where the textual description of the image (or tags) would be its content. By doing this you now have a document retrieval (or matching) problem, where the "given text" would be a query and the description of each image would be the "documents you can retrieve".

If this make sense you could use [Lucene] (http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to retrieve documents based on any implemented model.

Comment: @ElKamina Exactly. I totally agreed with you. So for now I would assume that the pictures that I can use are well tagged with texts. My question is still how to find the appropriate picture when given a text.

Comment: @miguelmalvarez That's interesting! Could you give me more details about the models for doing such document retrieval. Seems now, the queries are very long, and the data documents are very short in my case.

Comment: @KelvinLee If data is very small, you should use expansion. Eg. Use synonym dictionary to add all the synonyms etc. Search for query expansion (although you are not exactly doing query expansion)

Comment: you can indeed follow @ElKamina suggestion of doing expansion. Either with synonyms or relationships based on the collection.

About the differences in length. In principle is not too much of a problem because even though you have few tags, you know they are VERY relevant and representative. For instance, "car" would most likely be used in a picture with a car...

Any ad-hoc retrieval model will do for the matching/retrival phase (e.g. BM-25, LM, ...) You can use any of the already define ones in Lucene. If you want to keep it simple you can also do a (very simplistic) cosine similarity...

Answer (score 1):

I think PLSA ([Probabilistic latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis)) would help. You can apply it to extract latent topics from text, then use these topics to retrieve over the tags of pictures.